# How can I draw and manage these arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to replicate the figure below:

[image]

I am having trouble figuring out how to draw arrows that are similar to the ones shown in the picture (i.e. the arrow head, and the different colors for the stroke and fill).

Also, what would be a good way to draw the entire diagram (especially when it comes to positioning everything correctly)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `shapes` library to draw arrows.
Here is a begining, you juste have to change the colors and adjust the position of your arrows.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={single arrow, thick,draw=blue,fill=cyan,single arrow head extend=1.5mm,minimum height=1.5cm}]
\node at (-1,1) {};
\node at (-2,2) {};
\node at (-1,-1) {};
\node[rotate=180] at (-2,-2) {};
\node[rotate=180] at (1,2) {};
\node[rotate=180] at (2,1) {};
\node at (1,-1) {};
\node[rotate=180] at (2,-2) {};

\draw[dashed] (-3,3)--(3,3)--(3,-3)--(-3,-3)--(-3,3);
\draw[dashed] (0,3)--(0,-3);
\draw[dashed] (-3,0)--(3,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]